# C++/CLI and C# Garbage collection before context switch

Tags: c#, c++-cli

At one point in time I was searching MSDN and found an app config setting that would force a garbage collection prior to a native to managed boundary context switch.  This would be useful for tracking down references that are improperly getting cleaned up before I meant them to.  I cannot for the life of me remember what that option was, does it ring a bell for anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about marshaling or about context switch due to the OS scheduling a new thread to run on a core?

Comment: It was a non-deterministic access violation exception that I was trying to solve.  I have C++/CLI Code that calls back into C# code and C# code that calls back into C++/CLI code. I think my delegate was getting garbage collected and then my callback from C++ would implode with an access violation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course a minute after I post the question I find the answer. It is the MDA or Managed Debugging Assistants: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx

Specifically this part: gcManagedToUnmanaged MDA.